# Image of probability measures under measurable mappings

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory

Given two probability measures on two probability spaces, ($\mu, X$) and ($\gamma, Y$), what's the sufficient and necessary condition such that there is a measurable mapping $f:X\rightarrow Y$, such that $f^*\mu = \gamma$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a complete classification of probability spaces up to a measure-preserving
isomorphism.

Specifically, consider a category whose objects are triples
(X,Σ,μ), where X is a set, Σ is a σ-algebra
of measurable subsets on Σ,
and μ is a probability measure on (X,Σ).

If we want to have a nice description of morphisms
in terms of equivalence classes of point-set maps, we must
also require that (X,Σ,μ) is a compact probability space
in the sense of Marczewski's 1953 paper
“On compact measures”, but without countability assumptions.
We also assume completeness, since this does not change
isomorphism classes, but makes it easier to define morphisms.

Morphisms (X,Σ,μ)→(X',Σ',μ') are equivalence classes of maps
of sets f:X→X' such that f*Σ'⊂Σ and μf*=μ'.
The equivalence relation identifies f and g
if for all σ∈Σ' the symmetric difference f*σ⊕g*σ
has measure 0.

The better-known equivalence relation of equivalence almost
everywhere reduces to the above one if the involved spaces are countably
separated (like the real line), but in general one must use the above definition.

The isomorphism classes of objects in the resulting category
admit a complete classification.

First, any object canonically decomposes as a coproduct (disjoint union)
of ergodic spaces, i.e., spaces for which the automorphism
group has no nontrivial invariant subsets.

Secondly, the ergodic spaces admit a complete classification as follows.
First, the discrete spaces are ergodic.
Secondly, the nondiscrete ergodic spaces are isomorphic
to the infinite product of I copies of {0,1} (a discrete space),
where I is an infinite set, whose cardinality is the only invariant
of the resulting space.

The classification of isomorphism
classes (first stated for Boolean algebras Σ/N) is known as the von Neumann–Maharam theorem.
A 1965 theorem by Cassius Ionescu Tulcea (with subsequent
improvements by Vesterstrøm–Wils, Edgar, Graf, Fremlin, Rinkewitz) shows that isomorphisms classes of such
Boolean algebras coincide with appropriately defined
isomorphism classes of probability spaces.

(This claim also holds if we remove the requirement that (X,Σ,μ) is compact,
in which case we must first localize the category at all morphisms f
such that the induced map of Boolean algebras Σ'/N'→Σ/N is
an isomorphism.  Completeness can also be removed if the notion
of measurability is adjusted accordingly: elements in f*Σ' must be symmetric differences of elements in Σ and a subset of a measure 0 set.)

Thus, the original question can be answered as follows:
there is a measurable mapping f:X→Y such that f*μ=γ
if and only if the decompositions of X and Y into their ergodic
components have the same measures for each type of ergodic summand,
and the discrete parts are isomorphic.

Comment: It is not that $\Sigma$ *is* a compact class, but rather that there *exists* a compact class $\mathcal{K} \subseteq \Sigma$ such that $\mu$ is inner regular with respect to $\mathcal{K}$ (*i.e.* that $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ is *compact* in the terminology used in Fremlin's *Measure Theory* volume 3). This cannot be replaced in the general case by any property of $\Sigma$, because there are $\sigma$-algebras that admit both compact and non-compact measures (*e.g.* the countable-cocountable $\sigma$-algebra), though of course all probability measures on a standard Borel space are compact.

Comment: You have also omitted the requirement that $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ have a lifting. Shelah proved that it is relatively consistent to ZFC that $([0,1],\mathrm{Bo}([0,1]), \lambda)$, $\lambda$ being the Lebesgue measure restricted to Borel sets, have no lifting. Since complete probability spaces always have a lifting, it follows that the Borel restriction of Lebesgue measure is not isomorphic to its completion in this model. (Von Neumann proved, on the other hand, that this space does have a lifting under the continuum hypothesis).

Comment: And you may call it the "von Neumann-Maharam theorem", but from my perspective that only refers to the existence of an isomorphism of measure algebras as complete Boolean algebras, not of measure spaces. The existence of an isomorphism of measure spaces requires substantial extra work due to Fremlin.

Comment: @RobertFurber: I certainly meant a compact measure, not just a set-theoretic notion.  I also added the completeness condition that I left out.

Comment: @RobertFurber: I must also say that the existence of point-set maps of measurable spaces is not due to Fremlin, but rather is a theorem by Cassius Ionescu Tulcea (see his 1965 paper in Comptes Rendus).  There were several subsequent improvements, see my paper https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.05284, where I try to list (hopefully) all contributors.

Comment: That sounds interesting, but a search of the [1965 Comptes Rendus](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/cb343481087/date1965) yields no papers by either Ionescu Tulcea.

Comment: @RobertFurber: Volume 261, pages 4961--4963.  Link: https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k4027h/

Comment: Thanks. That was the fault of the crappiness of the French National Library's website.

Comment: Unfortunately Lemma 5.10 in your arxiv paper is not correct, unless you assume the nonexistence of real-valued measurable cardinals. The problem is that Lemma 4.37 can only be used to prove that you have a morphism preserving arbitrary suprema for $\sigma$-finite enhanced measurable spaces, not the general localizable case you intend to apply it to there. Counterexample in next comment.

Comment: As a counterexample, assume that $X$ is a set such that there exists a countably additive probability measure $\mu : \mathcal{P}(X) \rightarrow [0,1]$ vanishing on singletons (so $|X|$ exceeds the first real-valued measurable cardinal), and $\nu : \mathcal{P}(X) \rightarrow [0,\infty]$ is the counting measure. Let $f : (X, \mathcal{P}(X), \mu) \rightarrow (X, \mathcal{P}(X), \nu)$ be the identity mapping. The only nullset of $\nu$ is $\emptyset$, so this is a premap of enhanced measurable spaces. The join of all singletons in $X$ is 1, but each singleton has $\mu$-measure zero ...

Comment: So the join in $\mathcal{P}(X)$ modulo the $\mu$-nullsets is $0$. The good news is: 1. This is essentially the only possible counterexample. 2. If $X$ is compact and $Y$ is strictly localizable, this situation cannot occur and $\mathcal{ML}$ only produces complete Boolean algebra homomorphisms. If you like, I can write a letter to you explaining the proof of this, which you can incorporate into your arxiv paper.

Comment: @RobertFurber: Thanks a lot for pointing this out!  Fortunately, the wrong half of Lemma 5.10 was not used anywhere, so I threw it away and added the missing reduction to the σ-finite case.  I posted a new version here: https://dmitripavlov.org/equiv.pdf, which will be uploaded to arXiv sometime soon.  Let me know if you see anything suspicious left or have any questions.  I also added your example (with an acknowledgment in the introduction) as Remark 5.11.

Comment: The new version looks fine to me.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely just [standard probability spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_probability_space) are sufficient for your purposes. All non-atomic such spaces are pairwise isomorphic.

Answer (score 1):

One sufficient condition is that the source space is nonatomic and the target space has the Borel sets of a Polish space as the underlying $\sigma$-algebra. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/359586/construction-of-brownian-motion/359614#359614) for pointers on how one can prove this.